# in Camunda, how can I differentiate a process Instance that terminated at ErrorEnd Event versus EndEvent?

Tags: camunda

I am new to Camunda, I want to understand how can I capture/get error information if a process instance terminated at ErrorEndEvent. For both ErrorEndEvent and EndEvent, the status is marked as 'COMPLETED'.
At the very least, how can I distinguish between the two?

```
REST API: engine-rest/history/process-instance

{
        "id": "72392151-8517-11ea-9313-0242ac110002",
        "businessKey": null,
        "processDefinitionId": "TestError:5:6ac37e20-8517-11ea-9313-0242ac110002",
        "processDefinitionKey": "TestError",
        "processDefinitionName": null,
        "processDefinitionVersion": 5,
        "startTime": "2020-04-23T04:03:53.532+0000",
        "endTime": "2020-04-23T04:03:54.669+0000",
        "removalTime": null,
        "durationInMillis": 1137,
        "startUserId": null,
        "startActivityId": "StartEvent_1",
        "deleteReason": null,
        "rootProcessInstanceId": "72392151-8517-11ea-9313-0242ac110002",
        "superProcessInstanceId": null,
        "superCaseInstanceId": null,
        "caseInstanceId": null,
        "tenantId": null,
        "state": "COMPLETED"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the history for the activities of the process instance:

```
{{rest_url}}/history/activity-instance?processInstanceId=4008cd81-8622-11ea-b8c7-9c899b574756&sortOrder=desc&sortBy=startTime
```

also see:
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/rest/history/activity-instance/get-activity-instance-query/

Example result:

```
[
    {
        "id": "Event_13nxum6:eac48940-8622-11ea-b8c7-9c899b574756",
        "parentActivityInstanceId": "4008cd81-8622-11ea-b8c7-9c899b574756",
        "activityId": "Event_13nxum6",
        "activityName": null,
        "activityType": "noneEndEvent",
        "processDefinitionKey": "OrderProcessProcess",
        "processDefinitionId": "OrderProcessProcess:1:27646e94-6998-11ea-9c0d-9c899b574756",
        "processInstanceId": "4008cd81-8622-11ea-b8c7-9c899b574756",
        "executionId": "4008cd81-8622-11ea-b8c7-9c899b574756",
        "taskId": null,
        "calledProcessInstanceId": null,
        "calledCaseInstanceId": null,
        "assignee": null,
        "startTime": "2020-04-24T19:58:31.398+0800",
        "endTime": "2020-04-24T19:58:31.398+0800",
        "durationInMillis": 0,
        "canceled": false,
        "completeScope": true,
        "tenantId": null,
        "removalTime": null,
        "rootProcessInstanceId": "4008cd81-8622-11ea-b8c7-9c899b574756"
    },
    {
        "id": "PrepareOrderTask:78b10b79-8622-11ea-b8c7-9c899b574756",
        "parentActivityInstanceId": "4008cd81-8622-11ea-b8c7-9c899b574756",
        "activityId": "PrepareOrderTask",
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

POST /engine-rest/history/activity-instance

Content-Type: application/json with following request body

```
{
  "processDefinitionKey": "ProcessID",
  "activityType": "errorEndEvent",
  "finished":"true",
  "sorting":
    [{"sortBy": "endTime",
    "sortOrder": "asc"
    }]
}
```

refer https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/rest/history/activity-instance/post-activity-instance-query/ for more details.